# How the asp.net database works on server?

Tags: database, server

I have created a Sign Up form in asp.net that is connected to the database so if i upload my files to the server will it still work fine as it works while debugging?

Comment: Do explain a bit more what you mean. If the server supports what you use, it will work.

Comment: I have created a Sign Up form .aspx in visual studio and the form is connected to LocalDB on my machine so if I publish the page and upload it to a server that supports asp.net and IIS then will the Sign Up form work with the database on the server as its working in my local machine,I mean will the database get copied exactly as it is on my local machine to the server machine and will it work

Answer (score 0):

If you have used simple .mdf file for your DB, you can upload it along with your web files, it will work.

If you are using SQL database, you will have to upload it on server and make required changes in connection string. You will have to update database server IP in your connection string.

Comment: Glad to know you found it :)